# How to return a status code from an endpoint that can then be handled by app.UseStatusCodePages() middleware?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

If I return `StatusCode(403)` or any other error code from an endpoint, any configuration of `app.UseStatusCodePages<whatever>` will be ignored.

I believe this is because the `StatusCode(<whatever>)` will automatically create a result object, and `UseStatusCodePages` only kicks in if there is an error status code and *no* content.

So how do I set a status code result in an IActionResult type endpoint and then return without setting any content so that `UseStatusCodePages` will handle the job of providing a suitable resonse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I have the `ApiController` attribute on the endpoint controller. One of the things this attribute does is to automatically create a `ProblemDetails` response body for any failed requests, and it is this that prevents `UseStatusCodePages` from having any effect.

The solution is to either remove the `ApiController` attribute if you do not require any of its features, or alternatively its behaviour of automatically creating `ProblemDetails` responses can be disabled using the following configuration in `Program.cs` (or `Startup.cs` in old style projects).

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
{
   options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the UseStatusCodePages will just be fired when the action result is the StatusCodeResult.

If you put some value inside the status codes, it will return the object result which will not trigger the UseStatusCodePages.

So I suggest you could directly use `StatusCodeResult(403)`, then if you want to put some value to the StatusCodeResult, I suggest you could put it inside the httpcontext's item.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        HttpContext.Items.Add("test","1");

        return StatusCode(403);
    }
```

Program.cs:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async statusCodeContext =>
{
   var  status =  statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Items["test"];
    // using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
    statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = Text.Plain;

    await statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
        $"Status Code Page: {statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode}");
});
```

Result:

[image]